# iOS get notified in parent viewcontroller when presented viewcontroller is dimissed

Tags: ios, swift, uipresentationcontroller, dismissviewcontroller

I have a view controller which presents another view controller and within the presented viewcontroller , user makes choices which will lead to many other notifications to be pushed but when we dismiss the presentation viewcontroller I would like original parent viewcontroller to be notified as viewwillappear is not firing.

Comment: I would expect viewWillAppear to get called in the parent view controller when the child is dismissed. (viewDidLoad won't get called again, but viewWillAppear is supposed to be called each time a view controller is about to be moved frontmost.)

Comment: @DuncanC That depends on the _modal transition style_: if the presented view is "full screen", then viewWillAppear will be called (more precisely: _may_ be called).  If it covers partially the view of the presenting view controller, then viewWillAppear will not be called - because it's already there and not appearing.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Good point. I thought about that after I posted my comment.

Comment: Like you said , It's presented modally and viewwillappear is not gettign called

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same question.  In my case, the presentedViewController is from a library which calls dismiss on the presentedViewController - so i have no access to anything in the presentedViewController, so I am looking for an answer purely from the parentViewController or maybe the containing window. (hopefully without the use of a polling timer or anything like that)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a block handler to your child controller to notify the parent controller with the user choice:

```
struct Choice {
  // whatever object that represents the user choice
}

class ChildController: UIViewController {

  var completionHandler: ((ChildController, Choice) -> Void)?

  func finishPresentation(with choice: Choice) {
     // Suppose this function is called when user picks something in the user interface
     completionHandler?(self, choice)
  }

}
```

Then in parent controller, assign the `completionHandler` to get notified with the user choice.

```
class ParentController: UIViewController {
  func presentChild() {
     let controller = ChildController()

     controller.completionHandler = { child, choice
        child.dismiss(animated: true) {
          // do something with the user choice
        }
     }

     present(controller, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using MVVM architecture and it's bit complicated to pass the data through handlers from one view model to another view model to another etc... Is there anyway I can get to know this via some viewcontroller lifecycle methods in parent viewcontroller ?

Comment: @DCT Not really, even though there are ways to figure this out on the presenting view controller. The problem then is, you only know that a UIViewController is about to be dismissed. But you actually need the _data_ the child passes back to the parent. The solution of Ben is perfect. ;)

Comment: @DCT this is not mentioned in the question. I don't think it really matters if you use models or not, you should have some sort of back channel to pass the data between controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You may post the notification from child when it's about to be dismissed and observe the notification in parent view controller.

In parent view controller

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(methodtobecalled(_:)), name: "childdismissed", object: nil)

 @objc func methodtobecalled(_: Notification) {
        
    }
```

In child viewcontroller when you choose to dismiss , send the notification

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "childdismissed", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
```

Adopt the class `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` in presented view controller

add below delegate methods

```
func presentationControllerShouldDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

func presentationControllerDidAttemptToDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   // Post the notification here
```

}

Comment: I'm looking for solution other than notification. Thanks

Comment: like ben mentiond , go with Block based viewcontroller ? or you may go with delegate based one

Comment: Sometimes the presentation is dismissed by simply pulling it down so in this case .. you have no way to call the notification

Comment: I've update my answer